# Why my geth node's pending queue in txpool is empty but miner.start() works?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

OS = Ubuntu 16.04

Geth version = v1.9.13-stable-cbc4ac26

Go version = go1.14.2

My node's syncmode is fast sync , it's blockNumber = 1 and mined 5 Eth in Ethereum public chain(network).
So does it mean that the node already synced successfully?
If it is, why the pending queue in txpool is always empty?

Answer (score 0):

You are not fully synced. `miner.start()` will begin mining when you are fully synced.